# Does the Artifactory open source (OSS) support npm?

Tags: npm, artifactory

The [Artifactory Comparison Matrix](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Comparison+Matrix) seems to indicate that npm and several other formats are not supported:

Is that correct?  I haven't been able to find any mention of it elsewhere in the documentation about npm.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

That's right. npm repositories are not supported in the Artifactort OSS. Only Maven, Gradle, Ivy, SBT, and Generic repository types are supported.

However, if it's relevant for you, you can still use Artifactory on SaaS for free, by registering to the free tier program:
https://jfrog.com/start-free/.